# WindowsのVSCodeで、Macの共有フォルダが読み取れないようです。

Tags: vscode

・VSCode以外のエディタでは開けたりします

・他のWindowsの共有フォルダならVSCodeで開けます

・ただ、他のソフトでも少し変な挙動をするような感じもします

仕様でしょうか？対策はありますでしょうか？

Comment: 「共有フォルダが読み取れない時」「少し変な挙動をする」の辺りをもう少し詳しく説明できるとアドバイスも付きやすいと思います。 / 開けない時に何かエラーメッセージ等が表示されていれば、それらも追記してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「'test1' を開くことができません: ファイル (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, stat '\\MAC\test1') を読み取ることができません。」というメセージが出ます

Comment: この辺の記事を参考に。[MacとWindowsでファイル共有するには](http://iphone.f-tools.net/Question/PC-File-Sharing.html), [Macの共有フォルダにWindowsからアクセスして読み書き](https://hack-le.com/mac-win-smb/), [仕事効率化！MacとWindows間のファイル共有テクニック 3 選](https://navi.dropbox.jp/mac-windows-file-sharing)